# Can I really do anything with a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

The problem I have is users not taking the time to properly read a question and then posting another answer from somewhere else which doesn't really answer the question.

This is then marked as a duplicate and then the system tells you to make an edit or open a new question but in my experience this is what happens:

Make an edit- This has no effect and no one ever re-opens the question. I am not even sure exactly what happens when you make the edit and whether or not it needs to be reviewed by the person who marked it as duplicate?

Open a new question: Potentially just the same thing could happen, but now you have two questions open, negatively effecting your account.

The above is in response to various questions I have posted on various SE sites. The question's were marked as duplicate with question's that already provides an answer that I know but if the person responding to my post's had read a little further into it, would have seen that I was being more specific.

Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, so I have provided edits but like previous times I expect nothing will happen at all.

Comment: if question isn't reopened after edit, this only means there is something wrong with the edit. Edit automatically pushes question into [reopen review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats), and if it stays closed this only means three reviewers looked at it and weren't convinced. Reopening wrongly duplicated questions should be [as easy as it gets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773)

Comment: Ok but as far as I can tell, there is no way to tell when and if it has been reviewed, or if it has, does it still have the same problem or does it need anything else.

Comment: reopen review queue is very short and fast at SO, if the question didn't get reopened in a day, one can assume that edit failed to convince reviewers

Comment: Does it have to be reviewed by the person who marked it as duplicate?

Comment: @connersz no, any user with 3K rep and above can review  Reopen items. It's actually very rare that the same person who voted to close will also review the reopen as we get no notification whatsoever and many users love to review.

Comment: Well this question should provide a good example, which according to your comments should be reviewed very quickly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So I updated this question 3hrs ago to take it 'off-topic' but still not change. Are you still so confident that they're always reviewed?

Comment: @connersz it did appear in the review queue and [was reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/27912). Three high rep users decided to leave it closed. So yes, I'm still confident.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So like I said before, how can I see what the reason was, surely the objective is to have good quality questions so in my opinion the feedback would be valuable when updating it.

Comment: @connersz I fear you can't. You'll just have to trust the high rep users to make the right decision and you can always flag your own question asking to reopen if you really feel that way. No guarantee this will be done of course, but you're allowed to try.

Comment: I expect it has been jumped on because I made a comment about how questions are review when closed or marked as 'off-topic'.

Comment: One way to prevent this in future is to have a section linking to the related questions where you explain the way in which your question is different or why those answers don't apply - this helps people realise the first solution they reach for is one you already tried.

Comment: @connersz no, when an edit is made an automatic reopen review created.

Comment: @AndrewC I agree with you, however in most cases I have tried certain things myself without prior need from SE so unless I purposely go searching for every related post and then explain within the question that it is not relevant then I cannot see how it would help. Furthermore this is also a question about how to handle questions marked as OT or closed and how it is possible to get the question to a good level so it can be re-opened. It seems like there is no way to understand what the requirements are following each review.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I would very much appreciate any of mods explaining in here why the question is still off-topic.

Comment: @connersz sorry, I didn't bother to look into it in depth myself. Now did and cast a reopen vote which should send it again to the queue. Hopefully, it will catch this time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for taking your time to throw some light on this. I know that when you mark down a question it says something like 'please provide information on how the user can improve the question' because it is trying to help you provide feedback. But don't you think it would be beneficial for those voting it to be put on-hold to do the same? That way whoever opened the question can do whatever required to improve it's quality.

Comment: @connersz the message appears only until a user gets certain amount of reputation (1000 or 2000, dunno exactly) and close privilege is gained at 3000. At this level, the system trusts the users who vote to close to leave a comment if they think it's needed. And indeed, the very first comment here is exactly what was needed and it explains the initial closing, so no additional comments were needed from those who closed.

Comment: Is it better to close a question or improve it?

Comment: @connersz Questions are closed *so that they can be improved*.  If, while closed, a question is improved sufficiently, it can be reopened.  If not, it can either stay closed or be deleted.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/147247 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19126/147247